# Realize when an object is changing some values

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using C++ and MFC (dialog based).

In my main Dialog I have an object called memmory (`unsigned short*`, simulates a PLC memmory) and another object called `test` of class `A`.

The object `test` has a reference to memmory and is able to change it. In the main dialog there are some graphs that depend on the values of memmory.

My question is: how can I update this graphs when the object `test` change any value of memmory?

I could give the object `test` a reference to the dialog and whenever test changes memmory just call a dialog method to update the graphs. This is not possible since object `test` (class `A`) CAN'T have a reference to a dialog (for some reason).

The other option would be to set a timer and re-do the graphs every X ms, but this option seems a bit dirty to me.

I thought that the object test could send a message `PostMessage` everytime it changes memmory, but in order to do so I need a reference to the dialog, right?

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Take a look OOP design pattern "Observer": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern. You test class could be an "Observable" one, and the class you want to know about memory changes could be "Observer" one.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate memmory inside a class `M` that will accept subscribers of type `IMemmoryChanged` interface. One of the subscribers would be the main dialog. The interface can have an abstract function `OnChange()`. You can implement the `IMemmoryChanged` interface inside the main dialog.

When main dialog is created you can create the `M` object and call `M.AddSubscriber(dialog)`

`M::SetMemmory(unsigned short value)` will change private memmory object and also notify all its subscribers (one of the subscribers is the main dialog).

So when test `A` calls `M.SetMemmory`, main dialog will be notified.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify test class, one possible design solution is to use pattern ["Observer"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_patternsd). The generic way is to let your `Test` class inherit `IObservable` interface, providing API for observers subscribing and unsubscribing. At the same time let your graph classes and any classes you want to know about changes in memory, to inherit `IObserver` interface, providing API to notify object about some important events for it.

When something important changes within observable, p.e. it changes PLC memory, you can notify all subscribed observers using `IObserver` API.

You can make your Observable class an ["Singletone"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to provide global access for it. Also you can use any appropriate STL container to store observers list within observable(`Test` class).

**Important** thing is not to forget to unsubscribe observer when it destructor. Unless your observable class can try to notify some object which doesn't exists anymore in fact.

You can use much more simplified "Observer" approach with concrete methods directly in your classes, not using interfaces, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a reference to the dialog if you use `::PostMessage(hwndDialog,...)` if you initialize class `A` with the dialog's `hwnd`. That means class A will not need to `#include` the dialog class h file.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a fully working example of `Observer` pattern. It is a simple example it is not intended to be perfect, for instance the `name` attribute of `Observable` class is a design
 issue.

I hopr it helps you to see better how `Observer` pattern works.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Observer
{
public:
    Observer(){};
    void notify(const char* name){
        cout << "Notyification from: " << name << endl;
    }
};


class Observable
{

public:
    Observable(const char* name):name(name){};
    // You can redefine in observable child classes the behaviour of notify_change.
    virtual void notify_change(){
        for (vector<Observer>::iterator it=observers.begin(); it != observers.end(); ++it)
        {
            (*it).notify(name);
        }
    }

    inline const char* get_name() {return name;}

    void register_observer(Observer obj){observers.push_back(obj);}
    // You should add something like unregister_observer too.

private:
    const char* name;
    vector<Observer> observers;
};


class Boss: public Observer {

public:
    Boss(){};

};

class Worker: public Observable {
public:
    Worker(const char* name):Observable(name){}
    void stop_working(){
        notify_change();
    }
};


int main()
{

    Boss some_boss;
    Worker some_worker("You");

    some_worker.register_observer(some_boss);

    some_worker.stop_working();

    return 0;
}
```